# Converting a cURL POST in php to vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, php, curl, post, xmlhttprequest

I need to take the following php code and convert it to javascript. I do not have access to jQuery for this so it needs to be in vanilla javascript. Can anyone help?

```
$username = "super";
$password = "duper";

$auth = base64_encode($username . ":" . $password);

$curl = curl_init();

$headers = array(
    'Authorization: Basic ' . $auth,
    'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Accept: application/json'
);

$fields = http_build_query(array(
    'action' => 'SKIP',
    'textword' => '12345',
    'number' => '1234567890'
));

$url = 'https://api.someplace.com/what/who';

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);

$resp = curl_exec($curl);
```

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help.

Comment: Stahp, this idea is horrifically susceptible to CORS issues.

Comment: If there is a better way I'd love to hear it.

Comment: Define "better"; if you are referring to proper then the CURL request is proper. If you wish to continue with the headache then just load up jQuery and crack open [`AJAX`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)